# Why does the mysql % permission not work for all remotes on EC2?

Tags: mysql, dns, amazon-ec2, database-permissions

I had a mysql admin issue with permissions on `%` hosts.

1. EC2_DB launched with IP `10.55.142.100` and DNS `ip-10-55-142-100.ec2.internal`
2. EC2_web launched with IP `10.55.142.144` and DNS `ip-10-55-142-144.ec2.internal`
3. EC2_DB and EC2_WEB are in the same security group with access across the DB port (3306)
4. EC2_DB has a mysql DB that can be reached locally and fully administered by the DB root user.
5. EC2_DB mysql DB has a remote user `'my_user'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD 'password'`
6. A bash call to mysql from EC2_WEB fails: `mysql -umy_user -p -h ip-10-55-142-100.ec2.internal`, as does host references to the explicit IP, public DNS, etc.

---

Step 6 seems to fail because the mysql DB has the wrong user permisions.  It needed this:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'my_user'@'ip-10-55-142-144.ec2.internal' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD 'password'
```

I would like to think that `%` would work for any remote server, but I did not find this to be the case.

---

Please let me know why I cannot use `%` here.

As it stands now, I will need to add the host-specific permissions for every client in my cluster, which is much more overhead (despite the improved security)

Comment: What error do you get on attempting to connect in step 6?

Comment: It's out of my buffer now, but it was something like `error, permission denied for 'my_user'@'ip-10-55-142-144.ec2.internal'`